# Do Ascension's small box expansions work well with the other big boxes?

Tags: deck-building, expansions, ascension

I currently own **Chronicle of the Godslayer** and **Return of the Fallen**, which are a paired set, so they work very well together.

I'm having trouble locating a copy of **Storm of Souls**, but I could pretty easily pick up **Immortal Heroes**.

Would **Immortal Heroes** work well alongside CotG/RoTF, or is it better to 1) play it as a standalone or 2) combo it with SoS?

That's my specific situation, but an answer that more broadly addresses combining boxes from different "blocks" would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I have played all combinations of sets up through and including Realms Unraveled.

Here are my thoughts:

- Immortal Heroes will mix in fine with RoTF and CoTG.
- Immortal Heroes played all on it's own would grow stale quickly
- Immortal Heroes and Storm of Souls together is an fun block in and of itself - maybe more fun than CoTG and RoTF.

If you have an iPhone or iPad I highly recommend the Playdeck implementation of the Ascension game - it costs a few bucks and you can play online with strangers, friends, or against the AI computer.